# Firebase JSON access permission denied even already login with Firebase Auth

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I already make Firebase Auth with email and password and I can retrieve my data. But, when I access my JSON file directly from web browser, it shows me `permission denied` even I already login. I use standard Firebase Rules, is this normal ?

```
`    {
      "rules": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth != null"
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your access token in your url.

Example :

```
https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/name.json?access_token=<TOKEN>
```

[Here the documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth)

Comment: i still dont understand with documentation, can you give me simple code to get my token ?

Comment: You need to create your own token with : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens or get the access token from a firebase user.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to validate the answer to close the question if it's revolved for you